# generating tokens and sending them to users

Tags: django, security, server, backend

I am trying to implement the account activation and password reset functionalities and I would like to review the theory.
I currently have 2 tables, user and token table. The user signs up. I save the user in the db, generate token and send it via email. So here's how I am tackling the problem: I am creating a 16bytes token and using this to create the link e.g`http://localhost:1200/api/activation/<token>`. However, in the db I am storing the hashed token (hashed with sha256). Then, theoretically, when the user clicks on the link, I perform sha256 on the token and see if it matches with the one stored in the database, right? I think the reason it is recommended to store the hash inside the db is because if the attacker has access to the db, he cannot impersonate the user (it still needs the original token), right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Simple JWT provides a JSON Web Token authentication backend for the Django REST Framework. It aims to cover the most common use cases of JWTs by offering a conservative set of default features. It also aims to be easily extensible in case a desired feature is not present.

Follow for more details [Django JWT Token](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I did not ask for jwt and usually you don't implement password_reset_tokens with jwt

Answer (score 0):

I think that your approach is correct. The point about hashing the token is right.